# Is the first-order theory of rational numbers with addition and equality decidable?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I know that:

- the first-order theory of natural numbers with addition and equality is decidable
- the latter with also multiplication is undecidable

What about rational numbers with just addition and equality?
Based on the fact that one can define a bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$, I would expect this theory to be decidable, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Doesn't $(\mathbb{Q};+,0)$ have full quantifier elimination?

Comment: @NoahSchweber you've gotta stop doing that ;) I was about to comment the same thing -- this is the theory of torsion free divisible abelian groups, which is known to have quantifier elimination (so it's decidable). Iirc this is in Marker's book

Comment: @HallaSurvivor To get decidability, you need *effective* quantifier elimination, together with a decision procedure for quantifier-free sentences. That is, you need be able to compute a quantifier-free equivalent for every sentence, and then compute whether that quantifier-free equivalent is actually true. But yes, the theory of torsion-free divisible abelian groups has both.

Comment: An alternative argument: The theory of nontrivial torsion-free divisible abelian groups is categorical in uncountable cardinalities (because the cardinality of such a group is its dimension as a $\mathbb Q$-vector space when uncountable), hence complete. And it's computably axiomatized, hence decidable.